# Why the input breaks after a space character

Tags: c, string, space

Hello guys!

Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* getStr( char *c ){
    scanf( "%s" , c );
    return c;
}

int main(){
    char str[ 100 ];
    getStr( str );
    printf( "%s" , str );
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please explain why is the string printed only until the first "space".
i.e.

input: asd asd

output: asd

Comment: I smell buffer overflow.

Comment: i don't know accurately but try to print `c` in `getStr` function before returning it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's what `scanf` does. If you want to read a string till newline, use `gets` **EDIT:** or its buffer-overflow-safe cousin `fgets` (thanks, @JayC)

Comment: Or its buffer-overflow-safe cousin 'fgets'

Answer (score 14):

That's the contract of `scanf` (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html).  It reads until the next whitespace encountered.

You could change your format string to read in two strings as `"%s %s"` which will read two strings separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

From the `scanf` man page:

```
Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters
```

That answers your question.

If you need to match whitespace as well then you may need to process it in a loop, or just read it using more traditional methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input strings with spaces you can also use fgets() function as shown below:

```
char str[50];
printf("Enter a string: ");
fgets(str,50,stdin);

printf("%s",str);  //print the accepted string
```